# How to create new column using row data using dplyr

Tags: r

I want to create new column and name it using data from another column within the same data frame. My dataframe my_data looks like:

| Cars | Colour |
| --- | --- |
| toyota | red |
| benz | white |
| bmw | blue |

and I want my final data frame to look like:

| Cars | Colour | toyota | benz | bmw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| toyota | red | red | white | blue |
| benz | white | red | white | blue |
| bmw | blue | red | white | blue |

Comment: Please post usable data using `dput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a copy of `Cars` and `Colour` column, get the data in wide format and use `fill` to change the `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_data %>%
  mutate(name = Cars, 
         value = Colour) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  fill(toyota:bmw, .direction = 'updown')

#  Cars   Colour toyota benz  bmw  
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#1 toyota red    red    white blue 
#2 benz   white  red    white blue 
#3 bmw    blue   red    white blue
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
my_data <- structure(list(Cars = c("toyota", "benz", "bmw"), Colour = c("red", 
"white", "blue")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

For example like this

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)
n=10
df = tibble(
  id = 1:n,
  Cars = sample(c("toyota", "benz", "bmw"), n, replace = TRUE),
  Colour = sample(c("red", "white", "blue"), n, replace = TRUE)
) 

df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Cars, values_from = Colour)
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
# id benz  toyota bmw  
# <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#   1     1 white NA     NA   
# 2     2 white NA     NA   
# 3     3 NA    blue   NA   
# 4     4 NA    NA     white
# 5     5 NA    white  NA   
# 6     6 NA    white  NA   
# 7     7 white NA     NA   
# 8     8 red   NA     NA   
# 9     9 NA    NA     blue 
# 10    10 blue  NA     NA   
# 
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Colour, values_from = Cars)
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
# id white  blue   red  
# <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#   1     1 benz   NA     NA   
# 2     2 benz   NA     NA   
# 3     3 NA     toyota NA   
# 4     4 bmw    NA     NA   
# 5     5 toyota NA     NA   
# 6     6 toyota NA     NA   
# 7     7 benz   NA     NA   
# 8     8 NA     NA     benz 
# 9     9 NA     bmw    NA   
# 10    10 NA     benz   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `transpose` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
cbind(setDT(my_data), data.table::transpose(my_data, 
    make.names = 'Cars')[rep(1, nrow(my_data))])
```

-output

```
     Cars Colour toyota  benz  bmw
1: toyota    red    red white blue
2:   benz  white    red white blue
3:    bmw   blue    red white blue
```

#### data

```
my_data <-  structure(list(Cars = c("toyota", "benz", "bmw"), Colour = c("red", 
"white", "blue")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```